# Creating a globally accessible class instance on a cuda kernel

Tags: c++, object, cuda

I want to run a Cuda kernel parallelizing some processes. I encountered a problem with the functionality of cudaMemcpy which only seems to produce shallow copies of objects. Due to this behavior of cudaMemcpy I am not able to operate the object that I copied onto the device memory properly. Therefore I tried to work my way around by copying the class members separetely onto the device and building the object right on the device.

Now my actual problem is that I only need one instance of the class on the device that shall be accessed by the parallel computations that should be performed right after the class instance has been created.

```
__global__ void some_kernel(double* a, double* b, int c, int N, int* check){

   my_class_a class_obj(a, b, c);
   
   int ii = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

   if (ii < N){
      my_class_b current_obj();
      current_obj.calculate_stuff(&class_obj);
      check[ii] = ii;
   }
}
```

So from the code above it can be seen that the one instance of my_class_a should be accessible by every instance of my_class_b created throughout the parallel computation. It's task basically consists in providing data stored in it's members by different methods. I want nothing else than to use the object class_object as if I would have passed it as an argument to the kernel but without the drawbacks of being just a shallow copy. So maybe it is something like assigning the instance of my_class_a to global device memory or something like this?

When I do it like this for example it works:

```
__global__ void some_kernel(double* a, double* b, int c, int N, int* check){
 
   int ii = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

   if (ii < N){
      my_class_a class_obj(a, b, c);
      my_class_b current_obj();
      current_obj.calculate_stuff(&class_obj);
      check[ii] = ii;
   }
}
```

But it is very inefficient and memory-consuming as I wouldn't need like several million copies of the same object that is also pretty large. I would have guessed thaht this should be pretty basic task as all the data stored inside the passed variables a and b are already on the device memory.

Comment: you could have a class a that only has pointers to memory as it's member variables, then initalyse an instance of that class in constant memory that points to the right address in global device memory. This would be accessible to all threads, and you would not waste memory.

Comment: Why don't you construct a deep copy on the host and pass it to the kernel?

Comment: As an alternative to constructing on the host, you could construct on the device (as you are doing here) but **in global memory**.  This could be done for example by using placement `new`.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be to construct your class a in global memory. If you choose to do it from device code, you could do it via placement `new`.  I'm demonstrating here using 2 kernel launches, because the kernel launch boundary guarantees the class a object in global memory is set up before any thread starts using it:

```
$ cat t169.cu
#include <new>
#include <cstdio>
struct my_class_a
{
    double f1, f2;

    __host__ __device__ my_class_a(double *a, double *b, int c)
    {f1 = (*a)/c; f2 = (*b)/c; }
};
struct my_class_b
{
    __host__ __device__ void calculate_stuff(my_class_a &a){
      printf("f1 = %f, f2 = %f\n", a.f1, a.f2);}
};
__global__ void setup(my_class_a *ca, double *a, double *b, int c)
    {
    new(ca) my_class_a(a, b, c);
    }
__global__ void some_kernel(my_class_a *ca, double *a, double *b, int c, int N, int *check)
{
    my_class_b current_obj;
    current_obj.calculate_stuff(*ca);
}

int main(){

  double *a, *b;
  my_class_a *ca;
  cudaMallocManaged(&a, sizeof(double));
  cudaMallocManaged(&b, sizeof(double));
  cudaMallocManaged(&ca, sizeof(my_class_a));
  *a = 2.0;
  *b = 4.0;
  int c = 2;
  setup<<<1,1>>>(ca, a, b, c);
  some_kernel<<<1,1>>>(ca, a, b, c, 1, NULL);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}


$ nvcc -o t169 t169.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t169
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
f1 = 1.000000, f2 = 2.000000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```